# Change directory from ROOT (C++)

Tags: c++, root-framework

I want to change the directory of ROOT to analyse a dataset in a certain project file. ROOT is stored here "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\ROOT 6.16.00". The data in the project file I want to access are in "C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\Project". How can I change the directory?

I have tried:

```
gSystem->cd("C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\Project");
```

but this does not work. The error which appeared was
\U used with no following hex digits

> " use of undeclared identifier 'cd' "

Comment: The error : " use of undeclared identifier 'cd' " appears.

Comment: Does [TSytem::ChangeDirectory](https://root.cern/doc/v616/classTSystem.html#a8b3ecebf4c55e5e9111521906919aa3c) not do what you want? Or edit the global [const char  *gRootDir;](https://root.cern/doc/v616/TSystem_8h_source.html) directly?

Comment: I suspect the problem is how c++ deals with backslashes and windows's use of them in directory names. I.e. from C++'s point of view `\U` is a single character (`\n` = newline, `\t` = tab, …). Since you actually want a backslash and not escape any other character, try `gSystem->cd("C:\\Users\\aaa\\Desktop\\Project");` (i.e. use two backslashes, of which the first means "now comes a special character" and the second "just a backslash", to get a single backslash).

Comment: It did not work for me but I managed to run everything by using root on a Linux terminal.